# APKinspector - Find String from Strings in SideView - Shortcut?

Tags: android, string, apk, shortcut, inspector

Searching for this has become exasperating - failing after three weeks of searching! So I hope one of you can tell me how I can kind of **open a string that is shown in the APKInspector's SideView Strings list**. Or rather opening the Method/Class it can be found in.

I tried everything that came to mind before starting to search. 
If the solution is easy&&I'm too stupid to feel free to punish me.

**Otherwise:** Thank you so very much in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no link between the strings listed and their source (class, method, etc.), so unfortunately there is no easy solution.

For what it's worth, JEB (https://www.pnfsoftware.com/index.php) does provide this capability.  It's a commercial tool, but it's currently maintained much better than the open source alternatives.